# Need help in output for Oracle PLSQL Procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

Am currently working on an oracle PL SQL procedure to list the project numbers, titles and names of employees who work on a project.

I am able to write a procedure that is able to get this info. However, I can only draw one output at a time as such:

```
1001 Computation
Alvin
Peter
```

How can I change my code to output all of the entries at the same time while printing them as such:
[Fragment Example][Showing only 1st 3 entries]

```
1001 Computation: Alvin, Peter
1002 Study methods: Bob, Robert
1003 Racing car: Robert
```

[Current Code]

```
create or replace procedure PROJECTGROUPS(projectid IN WorksOn.P#%TYPE)
is
PID Project.P#%TYPE;
PNAME Project.PTitle%TYPE;
ENAME Employee.Name%TYPE;
CURSOR query is
select Employee.Name from Employee
left outer join WorksOn On Employee.E# = WorksOn.E#
where WorksOn.P# = projectid
order by Employee.Name ASC
fetch first 20 rows only;
--
--
begin
select P#, PTitle into PID, PNAME from project where project.p# = projectid;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(PID || ' ' || PNAME);
--
open query;
loop
fetch query into ENAME;
if query%NOTFOUND then exit;
end if;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(ENAME);
end loop;
close query;
end PROJECTGROUPS;
```

Comment: Use `PID` and `PNAME` in each loop pass in `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE`. Or you can join projects table with attendees table and process all the projects in one pass. But you'll need to order by P# to group attendees by project and check if the previous `PID` was the same to start new section.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use it in a single query and loop through it as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROJECTGROUPS (
    PROJECTID IN WORKSON.P#%TYPE
) IS
BEGIN
    FOR I IN (
        SELECT PROJECT_NAME,
               PTITLE,
               LISTAGG(EMP_NAME,
                       ',') WITHIN GROUP(
                    ORDER BY EMP_NAME
               ) AS EMP_NAMES
          FROM (
            SELECT P.P#              PROJECT_NAME,
                   P.PTITLE,
                   E.EMPLOYEE.NAME   EMP_NAME,
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                       PARTITION BY P.P#
                        ORDER BY E.NAME
                   ) AS RN
              FROM PROJECT    P
              JOIN WORKSON    W
            ON W.P# = P.P#
              JOIN EMPLOYEE   E
            ON E.E# = W.E#
             WHERE P.P# = PROJECTID
        )
         WHERE RN <= 20
         GROUP BY PROJECT_NAME,
                  PTITLE
    ) LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(I.PROJECT_NAME
                             || ' '
                             || I.PTITLE
                             || ' : '
                             || I.EMP_NAMES);
    END LOOP;
END PROJECTGROUPS;
```

Also, your query is not actually outer joined as you have used the condition in the `WHERE` clause.

```
left outer join WorksOn On Employee.E# = WorksOn.E# -- you want outer join
where WorksOn.P# = projected  -- but the outer join is converted to inner join
```